# Protecting or Compare PDF Document

Tags: .net

I have a requirement, where we need to make sure that the document [PDF] we recieved electronically is same as the one we sent out.

ours is a document exchange company and we recieve and send lot of documents from and to out side, some times user have to send documents to us which we have sent them before, we want to make sure that the document is same and no changes were made by using some tools like photoshop or pdf editor.

One way i see is compare each byte, but not sure if we have any other tools..?

our project built using .Net 3.5, VB

Any help will be great

Thank you
Venu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could extract all the content to a txt file with `Ghostscript` and `pstotext` and then operate on the txt file.(sizeof, diff, etc.). Or maybe adopt `digital signature`?

Comment: Ghostscript is huge overkill for something like this.

Comment: Probably you're right, but could be an alternative(if the documents are not very large, though).

Comment: Thing is, user can send the same pdf file or he can print do his business (show it to some supervisor or something) and scan it back to us.

Comment: @siri: if the document is scanned, even if you have got the best ocr software for digitally reconstruct the dcument, I think you should consider other solutions, uman resources perhaps.

Comment: Thank you, I was thinking the same, but just wanted to see if there is some thing out there...

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using a Hash algorithm. It will be much faster than comparing each file byte by byte.

This example is c# but you can easily convert to VB.Net for your needs - http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/kirtan007/compare-two-files-with-hash-algorithm/

Comment: Sounds good to me, but still is there any other plug ins or third party packages to do this job..?

Comment: Why do you need a third party package when you can write 10 lines of code to do it?